# Cannot manipulate array produced with string.match

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have produced an array using:

```
var arr = [];
arr = string.match(/(?:^| )([a-z]+)(?= [A-Z])/g);
```

This works as expected and the array is full and can be seen using console.log or alert().

The array consists of words which I need to filter, so I am trying to use .splice to remove unwanted instances of the same word using:

```
for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (arr[i] === 'jim') {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

The *for* loop doesn't recognize any instances of, for instance, 'jim' in the array although there are several.

I tried the loop using an array I made myself and it worked fine, i.e.:

```
arr = ['jim', 'bob', 'arthur', 'jim', 'fred']
```

I have also tried the following which reports that 'jim' !== 'jim' as well as the other names not equalling 'jim'. Again this loop works fine with the self-assigned array.

```
var i = arr.length;
while ( i-- )
if (arr[i] === 'jim')
    arr.splice(i, 1);
else
    alert( "'" + arr[i].toString() + "' !== 'jim'" );
```

What is it about the array produced by the *string.match* that I am not understanding?

Comment: @user2343618: I can't work out what your regular expression is supposed to be matching nor have you specified the input string, but I'm guessing there are some whitespace characters or other special characters in the matches, e.g. a space at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You can save a lot of time by using `Array.filter()`:

```
arr = arr.filter(function(x){
   return x.trim() !== 'jim';   
});
```

Comment: note though that `.filter()` is not cross browser compatible if you're looking to support some older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

[James is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466615/javascript-cannot-manipulate-array-produced-with-string-match#comment37865522_24466615) right: whitespace characters cause the problem here.

When I try your examples above the test alerts:
`' jim' !== 'jim'`.
The first part/bracket of your regular expression includes a whitespace character in the matched strings.

The generated array will most likely be something like: `arr = [' jim', ' bob', ' arthur', ' jim', ' fred']`.